# Original ROM for Samsung Galaxy S i9000

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, rom, downgrade

I've put a custom ROM on my Samsung Galaxy S I9000 and now I want to go back to my original ROM. I was wondering if there was a way to get the original ROM, that came with my device, from an official site somewhere.

I've searched this websites and other forums but the links were old and not valid anymore.

Comment: +1 was wondering the same after I'd installed an ICS rom. Will be interesting to see if the answers differ based on whether the device was rooted or not (which, in my case, it was).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a way, the answer is Yes. Although, I would not consider any of the sites where you would get the ROM from to be "official".

What you need to do is download ODIN3 (or hemidal) and use that tool to flash the Stock ROM on the device. Doing so will most likely require you to completely wipe the device to factory state.

I found a couple sites that do have the Stock Firmware, but I don't want to link to the ROM directly for a couple reasons. One, I don't know the legality of linking to a the Stock Firmware and if the file is no longer valid in the future, I do not want this post to be "out of date".

If you google "flash i9000 odin stock" you will likely find a couple different sources that have the files needed to flash back stock. When I did this, [the first site](http://phanse.wordpress.com/2012/01/22/tutorial-to-install-android-2-3-6-xxjvu-official-on-samsung-galaxy-s-gt-i9000/) had the 2.3 XXJVU release for the i9000, and the .pit file (which is also required when going back to stock, and the drivers. It also is a tutorial on how to flash it.

Comment: You also may be able to find a One-Click Odin for the I9000 on XDA. This is a prepackaged Odin which has no function other than to flash the stock rom.